# Is the set of continuously differentiable functions on [0,1] an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Is the set of continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1]$ an integral domain?

I considered the functions $f, g$ defined by

$f(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
0, & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2};\\
x-\frac{1}{2}, &\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1
\end{array}
\right.
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
g(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
x-\frac{1}{2}, & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2};\\
0, &\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1
\end{array}
\right. .$

Please check this.

Comment: Your functions $f$ and $g$ are continuous, but not differentiable, at $1/2$. You need to modify them a bit.

Comment: Well,first we need to be clear what the operations on the functions are. I assume the operations are composition of functions and functional addition i.e. for every x in [0,1], (f + g) (x) = f(x) + g(x). Is that it? Otherwise,your question makes no sense as stated.Until you make the problem clearer,I'm voting to close.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 One cannot generally compose functions $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ (continuously differentiable or otherwise) so that is certainly not the operation. There is anyway a standard ring structure on function spaces like $C^1([0, 1])$, where the addition and multiplication operations are function addition $(f + g)(x) := f(x) + g(x)$ and function mulitplication $(fg)(x) := f(x) g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, namely constructing an explicit counterexample by considering nonzero functions that are zero on subintervals that together cover $[0, 1]$.

But, neither $f$ nor $g$ are differentiable at $x = \frac{1}{2}$, and so neither is actually in $C^1([0, 1])$. To adjust your counterexample, you can simply replace the nonzero linear parts of your functions with functions that vanish at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ to higher order.

Comment: How can you judge this question if it's not clear what the operations on the ring are?I assume that means I was correct in assuming the ring operations are function addition and composition,yes?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 No, but see please my comment under the question.

Comment: but $f$ and $g$ vanish at $2^{-1}$ @ travis

Comment: so what's the modification

Comment: @Bobthebuilder That's true, but neither of them are differentiable at $x = \frac{1}{2}$, so they aren't even in the ring in the first place.

Comment: sir can u please help to construct I cant

Comment: For $f$ for example, you need to replace the part of the function on $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ with a function that makes $f$ continuously differentiable. This means that the value and first derivatives of the function at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ must both be zero. What is a function that has that property?

Comment: if I use $f(x)=(x-\frac{1}{2})^2$

Comment: Yes, that rule for the interval will do nicely.